# Using Python + BeautifulSoup to pick up text in a table on webpage

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to pick up a date on a webpage.

The original webpage source code looks like:

```
<TR class=odd>
<TD>
<TABLE class=zp>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><SPAN>Expiry Date</SPAN>2016</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
```

I want to pick up the ‘2016’ but I fail. The most I can do is:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.thewebpage.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

a = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("Expiry Date"))
```

And I tried:

```
b = a[0].findNext('').text
print b
```

and

```
b = a[0].find_next('td').select('td:nth-of-type(1)')
print b
```

neither of them works out.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options.

Option #1 (using [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), being very explicit about the path to the element):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<TR class="odd">
    <TD>
        <TABLE class="zp">
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        <SPAN>
                            Expiry Date
                        </SPAN>
                        2016
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
    </TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
span = soup.select('tr.odd table.zp > tbody > tr > td > span')[0]
print span.next_sibling.strip()  # prints 2016
```

We are basically saying: get me the `span` tag that is directly inside the `td` that is directly inside the `tr` that is directly inside `tbody` that is directly inside the `table` tag with `zp` class that is inside the `tr` tag with `odd` class. Then, we are using [`next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to get the text after the `span` tag.

---

Option #2 (find `span` [by text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument); think it is more readable)

```
span = soup.find('span', text=re.compile('Expiry Date'))
print span.next_sibling.strip()  # prints 2016
```

`re.compile()` is needed since there could be multi-lines and additional spaces around the text. Do not forget to `import re` module.

Comment: thanks alecxe for the guidance, it's in great details!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the css selector is:

```
import bs4

data = """
<TR class="odd">
    <TD>
        <TABLE class="zp">
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        <SPAN>
                            Expiry Date
                        </SPAN>
                        2016
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
    </TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
exp_date = soup.find('table', class_='zp').tbody.tr.td.span.next_sibling
print exp_date # 2016
```

To learn about BeautifulSoup, I recommend you read the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Well, I would better still rely on class names here. We don't know the real complete html that can contain other tr and table elements.

Comment: Yeah the css selector is more forgiving I guess.

Comment: You can specify classes too: `soup.find('table', class_='zp').tbody.tr.td.span.next_sibling`.